# How to extend/merge already existing type definitions from @types/angular-route?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-types

I need to add a new property to the `IRoute` interface from [@types/angular-route](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/angular-route)

I believe it's possible via the TypeScript feature [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html). But can't get it to work :(

This is the part I'm interested in:

```
// @types/angular-route
declare var _: string;
export = _;

import * as angular from 'angular';

declare module 'angular' {
    namespace route {
        interface IRoute {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

I tried a bunch of different approaches.

```
import * as angular from 'angular';

declare module 'angular' {
  namespace route {
    interface IRoute {
      label: string;
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
import * as ngRoute from 'angular-route';

declare module 'angular' {
  export namespace route {
    export interface IRoute {
      label: string;
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
import { route } from 'angular';

export interface route.IRoute {
  label: string;
}
```

and

```
export namespace route {
  interface IRoute {
    label: string;
  }
}
```

But to no avail...

I also looked at other SO questions but their solutions didn't work here :(

Comment: hate to do the classic stackoverflow response, but the first approach you wrote should work, and does work for me locally. Maybe for some reason tsc doesn't find\reach the `d.ts` file you wrote the definition in?
Try entering that directly in one of your ts files just for testing purposes

Comment: I wrote the definition file directly inside a package I'm using and added it to the types section of the package.json file. I know it's wrong but I was testing it :) Perhaps that is part of the issue

Comment: yeah, I would start by putting it inside your `src` folder or whatever folder syntax your'e using. `tsc` has a flag called ` --traceResolution` than can help you debug what files are being found

Comment: Yep it helped to put definition inside my src folder